# preventing users from logging in with one device at a specific period of time

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication, ip

there is an online testing website for students.
i want to prevent users to login from one device.
i mean if one person logged in from device A and even logged out, then other users can not logged in from device A, until a specific time. half hour for example.
what is the best and most simple method for this?
how to use device's IP to do this?
I'm using asp.net 4 C#

thank you very much.

Comment: On login page, you keep track of your "logic" and move on...

Comment: thank you but how should i fetch mac address?

Comment: You can not get the mac address on asp.net from what I know, you only can get the IP using the `HttpRequest.UserHostAddress`

Comment: @Aristos, Javascript, http://www.dottodotnet.com/2010/04/finding-clients-mac-address-via.html

Comment: @FeliceM The page you gave is use activex control, meaning you need to install a local dll that can read the mac, work only on IE, and only if user permits it, not work for me that I use chrome...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think IP is a good way to identify the device, since there are many people don't accessing internet directly but through a shared local router. And every web browser restricts websites accessing to local resources due to security consideration. So we can't get hardware information to identify a device, except using some techniques such as ActiveX. If you don't like ActiveX, you can PARTLY solve the problem using cookies. For every page a user requests during he/she logged in, you can write some cookies remember the time, and denies the log in operation in log in page's code, if the time in cookies was not fit. But if a user switches to another local account, or a different browser, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Get the MAC address of the device to make sure the same device is not connecting from a different IP. [Here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/2088/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-machine) there are several hints about how to get MAC address.
Then store the addresses and the time in your db and apply your logic.
I do not think you can count on the IP address because most of them are dynamic and especially with mobile devices it is very easy to connect from different networks.

Comment: thank you but i'm not using MVC and of course i'm new to asp.net. can you explain more clear.
thank you very much. :)

Comment: MVC or ASP there is no difference in the logic I am suggesting you. At user login save his device MAC address and or is IP to the DB together with the dateTime, search in the DB to check when the same user previous login was made and apply your logic. How to get MAC address and or IP address is just a detail.

Comment: Do you read what's on the link that you give ? or is the first google return ? In the link that you call "several hints about how to get MAC address", says that they can not read client's mac address, only the server/local can be read !